# Implement custom template rendering in String using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to implement a for loop in my Kotlin script. The task is for example `The actions are {% foreach a in trip.actions %} a.name {% endfor %}` and I have to identify her the for loop and interpret the string. The interpreted string if trip.actions are ["arrive", "load", "unload"] should result in "The actions are arrive, load, unload" etc.

Comment: What is `{% foreach a in trip.actions %} a.name {% endfor %}`? Are you trying to rewrite some other script using Kotlin?

Comment: I am trying to implement a kind of expression language.  This string represents a for loop for trip.actions which is an array/list. so a.name will be repeated for the number of items in trip.actions, and a.name represents the name attribute of an action which will be in iteration.

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to parse that string, and translate it into something like `"The actions are ${trip.actions.joinToString(", ") { it.name } }"`?

Comment: sort of. But the source string contains expressions like this -> {% foreach a in trip.actions %} a.name {% endfor %} , so I have to convert this string into the required one.